# Refreshing div with ajax causes checkbox to loose value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a small box that is part of a PHP-site that lists all members who attended a certain event. In the box there is also a checkbox that communicates with a database to store values of who attended. I want the box to update dynamically when someone checks the checkbox. The code I have is working good, and whenever the DIV is refreshed I get an updated list of members and correct count, but **loose both the checkbox value and the label**!

I am sure there is a simple solution I've missed, but after trying for hours I need someone to point me in the right direction. Whenever I press F5 to refresh, the label and correct checkbox value reappears.

**Javascript:**

```
function check_my_attendance() {
 var user_attending = Number(<?php echo in_array($_SESSION['username'],$attending_users) ?>);
 if (user_attending > 0) { $("label[for='attending_checkbox']").text("You attended!"); }
 else { $("label[for='attending_checkbox']").text("You did not attend."); }
 $('#attending_checkbox').prop('checked',user_attending);
 }

function set_attendance(cb) {
    if($(cb).is(":checked"))  {
        $("label[for='attending_checkbox']").html('Setting..');
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "setattendance.php",
                data: "gig="+<?php echo $ut ?>+"&action=1",
                cache: false,
                success: function(result){
                    $("#containerAttend").load(document.URL + " #containerAttend");
                    check_my_attendance();
                }
                }); }
    else {
        $("label[for='attending_checkbox']").html('Removing..');
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "setattendance.php",
                data: "gig="+<?php echo $ut ?>+"&action=0",
                cache: false,
                success: function(result){
                    $("#containerAttend").load(document.URL + " #containerAttend");
                    check_my_attendance();
                }
                }); }
    }

$(document).ready(function(){
    check_my_attendance();
});    
</script>
```

**PHP/Html:**

```
<div id="containerAttend">
<?php $query_attendance="SELECT link_attending.attended_memberid,link_attending.attended_gigid,members.username FROM link_attending
                        LEFT JOIN members ON (members.id = link_attending.attended_memberid) WHERE attended_gigid=".$ut;
    $result_attendance = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query_attendance);
    $attending_users = array();
    for( $i = 0; $i < mysqli_num_rows ($result_attendance); $i++)
            {mysqli_data_seek($result_attendance,$i); $usr=mysqli_fetch_array($result_attendance); $attending_users[] = $usr["username"];}
    $chkattendance = array_filter($attending_users);
    if (empty($chkattendance)) {$attendance_int = 0;} else {$attendance_int = count($attending_users);}
?>
<div id="list_attended">
<div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-5">
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading">
  <b><?php echo $attendance_int; ?> users attended:</b>
</div>
  <div class="panel-body">
<?php 
if ($attendance_int > 0) {foreach($attending_users as $usr_att) {echo "<a href='profile.php?user=$usr_att'>$usr_att</a>"." - ";} echo "<br>";}
if (login_check($mysqli) == true)
    {echo "<form><input id='attending_checkbox' type='checkbox' onclick='set_attendance(this)' />
    <label for='attending_checkbox'></label></form>";}        
else
    {echo "<br>Log in to set attendance!";}
?>
</div></div></div></div>
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Use `$("body #attending_checkbox")` instead of `$("#attending_checkbox")`... Same goes for label part....

Comment: Hmm.. I tested that now, but it didn't help?! You meant altering the value in the check_my_attendance function, right?

Comment: Can you do `console.log(user_attending)` and check what value of user_attending you are getting after every AJAX call?

Comment: Interesting! You're definitely onto something. I get the same value as when the page loads initially (0 or 1, depending on whether that user attended that event) whenever the checkbox is clicked. When I refresh in browser I get the correct (and opposite) value. I guess the error is somewhere in the check_my_attendance function then? Thanks for your help so far.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments, this is where I believe you can make changes and everything might just work fine for you

```
function check_my_attendance(result) {
  var user_attending = Number(<?php echo in_array($_SESSION['username'],$attending_users) ?>);
  if(typeof result != 'undefined') {
    user_attending = result;
  }
  if (user_attending > 0) {
    $("body label[for='attending_checkbox']").text("You attended!");
  } else {
   $("body label[for='attending_checkbox']").text("You did not attend.");
  }
  $('body #attending_checkbox').prop('checked',true);
}
```

In function set_attendance(), you can pass the result value to your check_my_attendance() function like this:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "setattendance.php",
  data: "gig="+<?php echo $ut ?>+"&action=1",
  cache: false,
  success: function(result){
    $("#containerAttend").load(document.URL + " #containerAttend");
    check_my_attendance(result);
  }
});
```

You can do `console.log(result)` and check what you are getting as result in in the after the AJAX Callback. If it is an empty string, you can add this line at the end of `setattendance.php` - `echo 1;` or `echo 0;`

I also created this fiddle as a small example for setting this checked property and label text. Even though I am not using any AJAX in it, I just wanted to let you know why we are using the **body** tag before **#attending_checkbox** in `$('#attending_checkbox')`. The basic reason behind showing it to you is that whenever a new DOM element is loaded or an old DOM element is replaced the old javascript doesn't work. So, you need to set the parent name and then the DOM id first, so that the JavaScript is able to locate the new element. -  https://jsfiddle.net/prateekkathal/3kbtp2am/

Thanks,